# HTC U Ultra: Turn off automatic software updates completely

Tags: updates, 7.0-nougat, ota-update, htc, application-autoupdate

I do not want to update any apps automatically. I want this to happen at home when I am not charged for data volume. Are these settings correct for my wish? If not, which settings do I have to change also? I do not care about possible security issues that may arise. I can update from home manually once in a while.

[image: Auto update apps]

Comment: Both. Good that you pointed out there are 2 update mechanisms. The Android version is 7.0.

Answer (score 2):

To stop apps from updating over mobile data, go to your play store, open the menu on top right, -> settings -> auto update apps -> WiFi only

Comment: That used to be the case and the updates started nevertheless. I chose "Do not auto-update apps." now. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

On Oreo 8.0 and should be similar on Nougat

**Apps:** Play Store Settings → Do not auto-update apps or Auto update over WiFi.

There is a third option Auto update at any time - Data charges may apply. By selecting this and selecting Auto -update for an  app you ( from 3 dots menu) you can select apps that you wish to update over data  connection

These settings do not apply to system apps like Play Store, instant apps and they get updated even on data

**OS updates:** in Developer options disable automatic system updates and manually update, since these are typically big size files and accidentally downloading costs data

In your case HTC seems to have a different UI ;  disable the second option to prevent accidental download as explained. System updates aren't that frequent anyway

Comment: In your comment to the other answer, you mentioned that updation was happening for some apps. It shouldn't , unless  update is enabled as explained in third paragraph